# Cannot connect my nodejs to mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, jdbc

My code is as below

```
    var JDBC = require('jdbc');
var jinst = require('jdbc/lib/jinst');
var Pool = require('jdbc/lib/pool');


// isJvmCreated will be true after the first java call.  When this happens, the
// options and classpath cannot be adjusted.
if (!jinst.isJvmCreated()) {
    // Add all java options required by your project here.  You get one chance to
    // setup the options before the first java call.
    jinst.addOption("-Xrs");
    // Add all jar files required by your project here.  You get one chance to
    // setup the classpath before the first java call.
    jinst.setupClasspath(['./jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar']);
}
var mySql = new JDBC({
    url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nodejs',
    drivername: 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver',
    minpoolsize: 5,
    maxpoolsize: 10,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root'
});
mySql.initialize(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

I have the jar in the folder and mysql running in my local. But i am getting the following error

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
] cause: nodeJava_java_lang_NoClassDefFoundError {} }
{ [Error: Error running static method
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nodejs
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
] cause: nodeJava_java_sql_SQLException {} }
```

Please help. Is there any initialisation commands neede in nodejs?

Comment: That's not pure nodejs, you should tell more about your setup, why do you have a java error for example? The error is quite explicit and typical java error, you don't have a mysql java driver installed, [there are a lot of questions about this kind of error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjava%5d%20No%20suitable%20driver%20found%20for%20jdbc%3amysql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code exactly and it works, I think your path is `setupClasspath()` is not good. Try using an absolute path, a relative path works only if the working directory is set like you expect:

```
if (!jinst.isJvmCreated()) {
    jinst.addOption("-Xrs");
    jinst.setupClasspath([__dirname + '/jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar']);
}
```